# SVN upgrade fails

Tags: macos, svn

When I tried to update my working SVN copy, I got the following error message,

```
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/path/to/repository' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

So I tried to execute the 'svn upgrade' command.
At first everything seems to be working, for every file in working copy I get the following message,

```
Upgraded 'path/to/file'
```

After the process is finished with looping over my working copy files I get the following error message,

```
enter svn: E235000: In file '/SourceCache/subversion/subversion-62/subversion/subversion/libsvn_wc/entries.c' line 1713: assertion failed (base_node || below_working_node)
Abort trap: 6
```

I work on a Mac OS X 10.9 machine with SVN 1.7.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade a repository or a working copy? It's a **critical** distinction. You can't upgrade a repository with `svn`, and you can't upgrade a working copy with `svnadmin`.

Comment: I meant upgrading my working copy. I will edit the question.

Comment: Are you certain that you're running svn 1.7? 1.7 can upgrade 1.6 WCs, but 1.8 cannot. Run `svn --version` to be sure. Worst case, check out fresh working copies - they're considered disposable.

Comment: svn --version gives version 1.7.10 (r1485443)

Comment: The problem is that I still have a lot of files to add and a lot of changes are not yet committed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was migrating my development files from an old system to a new system.  The old system had an older version of tortoise SVN that used the _svn folder.

More recent versions of svn use the .svn folder.

svn upgrade didn't work, so I did the following:

1) Backed up the folder with the source code, just to be safe.

2) Deleted any _svn folders.

3) Deleted the outdated files from the SVN Repository using SVN Manager.

3) Imported the latest files into the repository.

4) Checked Out the files back into the folder with the latest files.